# Wurtz Reaction with acidic alkyl halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides

My chemistry book says we cannot use alkyl halides containing acidic hydrogen for Wurtz reaction. Why is this so?

Comment: The intermediate is an alkyl sodium, a highly basic species which will be quenched by any proton source. Acidic hydrogens will also react directly with the sodium metal.

Answer (score 3):

The Wurtz reaction involves the reaction of alkyl halide with sodium in dry ether. In this reaction, two molecules of alkyl halide react to form a alkyl-alkyl chain and sodium halide is also produced -

$$\ce{R-X + 2Na + X-R ->R-R + 2NaX} \tag{$\ce{X}$ = halogen}$$

Now, sodium is a strongly electropositive metal, and is above hydrogen in the electrochemical series. Thus it replaces acidic hydrogen wherever it occurs. For example,

$$\ce{CH3COOH + Na ->CH3COO- Na+ + 1/2 H2}$$

So, sodium reacts with the acidic hydrogen present in the starting alkyl halide.

Also, acid-base reactions are, in general, faster than a substitution reaction. If there was no acidic hydrogen, alkyl sodium intermediate would have formed and an S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction would have taken place.

However, in this case, if any alkyl sodium intermediate is formed, it would accept the acidic hydrogen and convert into an alkane, stopping the reaction.

$$\ce{R- Na+ + H-M -> R-H + NaM}$$

(R = alkyl group, M represents the functional group or chain attached to the acidic hydrogen)